# Cannot find functions in call graph

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am beginning with Solidity and have begun experiencing this problem in my Contract. I created a test case to show the issue(pictured below with console log included) that is also getting the same error. Functions and events are not being recognized in the call graph and I am not quite sure why because they are explicitly there.

[image]